# Where can I control the critical temperature for a system shutdown?

Tags: linux, debian

I've hat a few shutdowns lately because of temperature problems:

```
Aug 23 06:50:19 genuine ACPI: Critical trip point
Aug 23 06:50:25 genuine Critical temperature reached (57 C), shutting down.
```

However I don't consider 57 C a real problem and would like to increase the number.

Question: where can I do this?

As asked by fpmurphy; the output of trip_points is:

```
critical (S5):           75 C
passive:                 73 C: tc1=4 tc2=3 tsp=60 devices=0xdd987338 
active[0]:               73 C: devices=0xdd987dd8
```

Comment: What is the output of cat /proc/acpi/thermal_zone/THRM/trip_points?

Comment: I added the output; I already accepted from radius, but you want to share more, please do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a setting in the bios. Generally it's the temperature of the CPU. 57° C is Ok for most of them but you should check your CPU spec to do not put the limit to high.

Comment: You're right. So simple, but didn't thought about that, thx!

Answer (score 0):

I would reckon that you can set acpid to watch for some trigger value and execute a script when it is triggered.

Comment: That sounds interesting, too! Any chance remembering how this could be accomplished?

Comment: not really.. but if you look around your acpi folder, you fill find scripts for all kinds of actions.